# irreducible curves over $F_q$ with arbitrary number of rational point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, algebraic-curves

There is an exercise in [these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/8320notes6.pdf) of Pete L. Clark that says that for every $N$ there exist a "nice" curve over $F_q$ that has more than $N$ points over $F_q$(q is fixed). Of course one can prove this using the Bertini type results of Gabber and Poonen but I think those results should be an overkill.

The hint for the exercise says that use a hyperelliptic curve defined by a polynomial with many rational points but I don't understand how that might help because the hyperelliptic curves over $F_q$ can't have more than $2q$ rational point. Is there an elementary proof for this exercise?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the cited works. Coding theory people often refer to the so called [Garcia-Stichtenoth tower](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01884295) for something similar (and extremal in terms of $N$ vs. $g$), and (for technical reasons) assume that $q$ is a square. The starting point is often what's known as the Hermitian curve, defined over $K=\Bbb{F}_{r^2}$ by the equation
$$y^r-y=x^{r+1},$$ when it is easy to show that the number of $K$-rational points is $r^3+1$. As $N$ grows, we obviously need more and more variables.

Comment: Hmm.  That equation needs a plus sign to make both sides to lie in the subfield $\Bbb{F}_r$ for all $x,y\in K$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen your confusion is warranted, since the defining equation for the Hermitian curve over $\mathbb{F}_{r^2}$ is $y^r + y = x^{r+1}$.

Comment: @Foobanana Correct, I only remembered afterwards that the l.h.s. should be the relative trace rather than anything Artin-Schreierly. Also, I'm mostly a characteristic two person, when this kind of sign errors won't hurt ya  :-)